# How can I sort csv data alphabetically then numerically by column?

Tags: sorting, awk, gnu

If I have a set of data that has repeating name values but with different variations per repeating value, how can I sort by the top of each of those repeating values? Hopefully that made sense, but I hope to demonstrate what I mean further below.

Take for example this set of data in a tab separated csv file

```
Ranking  ID     Year  Make        Model     Total
1        128    2010  Infiniti    G37       128
2        124    2015  Jeep        Wrangler  124
3        15     014   Audi        S4        120
4        113    2012  Acura       Tsx       sportwagon  116
5        83     2014  Honda       Accord    112
6        112    2008  Acura       TL        110
7        65     2009  Honda       Fit       106
8        91     2010  Mitsu       Lancer    102
9        50     2015  Acura       TLX       102
10       31     2007  Honda       Fit       102
11       216    2007  Chrystler   300       96
12       126    2010  Volkswagen  Eos       92
13       13     2016  Honda       Civic     1.5t        92
```

If you look in the Make column, you can see names like Acura and Honda repeat, with differences in the Model and Total column. Assume that there's 200 or so rows of this in the csv file. How can I sort the file so that the items are grouped by Make with only three of the highest in value under the Total column being displayed by each Make?

Expected output below

```
Ranking   ID      Year    Make     Model           Total
1         113     2012    Acura    Tsx sportwagon  116
2         112     2008    Acura    TL              110
3         50      2015    Acura    TLX             106
4         83      2014    Honda    Accord          112
5         31      2007    Honda    Fit             102
6         13      2016    Honda    Civic 1.5t      92
...
```

Here is my awk code so far, I can't get past this part to even attempt grouping the makes by total column

```
BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = "\t";
}
FNR == 1 {
        print;
        next;
}
FNR > 1 {
        a[NR] = $4;
}
END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_desc"
        for(i = 1; i < FN-1; i++) {
                print a[i];
        }
}
```

Currently, my code reads the text file, prints the headers (column titles) and then stops there, it doesn't go on to print out the rest of the data in alphabetical order. Any ideas?

Comment: You have 4 `Honda` entries with totals `112, 106, 102, 92`. Please explain the logic that discards `106`.

Comment: What if you had 4 Honda lines that all had the same top value, 3 that had the same next value, and 1 that had the third - would you want 8 Honda lines output or just 3 of the 4 lines that have the top value or something else?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet that was an error on my part when I was entering the values for the expected output, but  it should be 106. I've fixed it

Comment: @EdMorton if the same Maker had the exact same value for several models or even the same model, then the first three that are read should be the the ones displayed in the output.

Comment: None of the posted answers would do that but you've accepted an answer so you're unlikely to get other answers. You should probably ask a follow up question with that input/output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following assumes bash (if you don't use bash replace `$'\t'` by a quoted real tab character) and GNU coreutils. It also assumes that you want to sort alphabetically by `Make` column first, then numerically in decreasing order by `Total`, and finally keep at most the first 3 of each `Make` entries.

Sorting is a job for `sort`, `head` and `tail` can be used to isolate the header line, and `awk` can be used to keep maximum 3 of each `Make`, and re-number the first column:

```sh
$ head -n1 data.tsv; tail -n+2 data.tsv | sort -t$'\t' -k4,4 -k6,6rn |
  awk -F'\t' -vOFS='\t' '$4==p {n+=1} $4!=p {n=1;p=$4} {$1=++r} n<=3'
Ranking  ID   Year  Make        Model           Total
1        113  2012  Acura       Tsx sportwagon  116
2        112  2008  Acura       TL              110
3        50   2015  Acura       TLX             102
4        15   014   Audi        S4              120
5        216  2007  Chrystler   300             96
6        83   2014  Honda       Accord          112
7        65   2009  Honda       Fit             106
8        31   2007  Honda       Fit             102
10       128  2010  Infiniti    G37             128
11       124  2015  Jeep        Wrangler        124
12       91   2010  Mitsu       Lancer          102
13       126  2010  Volkswagen  Eos             92
```

Note that this is different from your expected output: `Make` is sorted in alphabetic order (`Audi` comes after `Acura`, not `Honda`) and only the 3 largest `Total` are kept (`112, 106, 102` for `Honda`, not `112, 102, 92`).

If you use GNU `awk`, and your input file is small enough to fit in memory, you can also do all this with just `awk`, thanks to its multidimensional arrays and its `asorti` function, that sorts arrays based on indices:

```sh
$ awk -F'\t' -vOFS='\t' 'NR==1 {print; next} {l[$4][$6][$0]}
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    for(m in l) {
      n = asorti(l[m], t, "@ind_num_desc"); n = (n>3) ? 3 : n
      for(i=1; i<=n; i++) for(s in l[m][t[i]]) {$0 = s; $1 = ++r; print}
    }
  }' data.tsv
Ranking  ID   Year  Make        Model           Total
1        113  2012  Acura       Tsx sportwagon  116
2        112  2008  Acura       TL              110
3        50   2015  Acura       TLX             102
4        15   014   Audi        S4              120
5        216  2007  Chrystler   300             96
6        83   2014  Honda       Accord          112
7        65   2009  Honda       Fit             106
8        31   2007  Honda       Fit             102
9        128  2010  Infiniti    G37             128
10       124  2015  Jeep        Wrangler        124
11       91   2010  Mitsu       Lancer          102
12       126  2010  Volkswagen  Eos             92
```

Comment: Never name a variable `l` as it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code.

Comment: Matter of taste. I perfectly see the difference between a `1` and a `l`. Never assume your preferred coding rules are universal.

Comment: It's not a matter of taste and it's not a preference - it's always hard to tell `l`s from `1`s and in some fonts it's totally indistinguishable. I once spent hours helping someone debug their program only to find one of the supposed `l`s was a `1` after retyping the whole thing. There is zero benefit to using a variable named `l` and it simply IS hard to tell what it is.

Comment: I cannot disagree more, sorry Ed. I always use `l` for `line`, `length`, next index after `i`, `j` and `k`... and I will not change this. If the font you use is difficult to read better change it than ask all coders on earth to avoid using names that look too ambiguous for you. But let's stop here, if you don't mind, this is really far from the OP's question.

Comment: You don't REALLY think I'm commenting due to an inconvenience of my own do you? Suggesting that people should adjust their font to read your code in whatever browsers, terminals, etc. they use is not useful. It's absolutely fine to use whatever you like in your code of course, and I'll drop the discussion here but don't be surprised if I comment again if you use it again in some future post as I may not remember this discussion and the advice is for the good of the whole community reading it anyway.

Comment: Last post on this, honest, I just happened to be working on some python and came across https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid which says `Never use the characters ‘l’ ... as single character variable names`, https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E741.html says `Variables named I, O, and l can be very hard to read.... Change the names of these variables to something more descriptive.` and https://betterprogramming.pub/clean-code-naming-b90740cbae12 says `never use a small letter l (el)...,as a name`. Just adding that so no-one thinks it's just my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk for arrays of arrays and `sorted_in`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR == 1 {
    print
    next
}
{
    rows[$4][$6][++numRows[$4,$6]] = $0
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    for ( make in rows ) {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_desc"
        cnt = 0
        for ( total in rows[make] ) {
            for ( rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows[make,total]; rowNr++ ) {
                if ( ++cnt <= 3 ) {
                    row = rows[make][total][rowNr]
                    print row, cnt
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Ranking ID      Year    Make    Model   Total
4       113     2012    Acura   Tsx sportwagon  116     1
6       112     2008    Acura   TL      110     2
9       50      2015    Acura   TLX     102     3
3       15      014     Audi    S4      120     1
11      216     2007    Chrystler       300     96      1
5       83      2014    Honda   Accord  112     1
7       65      2009    Honda   Fit     106     2
10      31      2007    Honda   Fit     102     3
1       128     2010    Infiniti        G37     128     1
2       124     2015    Jeep    Wrangler        124     1
8       91      2010    Mitsu   Lancer  102     1
12      126     2010    Volkswagen      Eos     92      1
```

The above will handle cases where multiple cars of 1 make have the same total by always just printing the top 3 rows for that make, e.g. gven this input where 4 Acuras all have 116 total:

```
$ cat file
Ranking ID      Year    Make    Model   Total
1       128     2010    Infiniti        G37     128
2       124     2015    Jeep    Wrangler        124
3       15      014     Audi    S4      120
4       113     2012    Acura   Tsx sportwagon  116
4       113     2012    Acura   Foo     116
4       113     2012    Acura   Bar     116
4       113     2012    Acura   Other   116
5       83      2014    Honda   Accord  112
6       112     2008    Acura   TL      110
7       65      2009    Honda   Fit     106
8       91      2010    Mitsu   Lancer  102
9       50      2015    Acura   TLX     102
10      31      2007    Honda   Fit     102
11      216     2007    Chrystler       300     96
12      126     2010    Volkswagen      Eos     92
13      13      2016    Honda   Civic 1.5t      92
```

this is the output showing just 3 of those 4 116 Acuras:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Ranking ID      Year    Make    Model   Total
4       113     2012    Acura   Tsx sportwagon  116     1
4       113     2012    Acura   Foo     116     2
4       113     2012    Acura   Bar     116     3
3       15      014     Audi    S4      120     1
11      216     2007    Chrystler       300     96      1
5       83      2014    Honda   Accord  112     1
7       65      2009    Honda   Fit     106     2
10      31      2007    Honda   Fit     102     3
1       128     2010    Infiniti        G37     128     1
2       124     2015    Jeep    Wrangler        124     1
8       91      2010    Mitsu   Lancer  102     1
12      126     2010    Volkswagen      Eos     92      1
```

If that's not what you want then move the `if ( ++cnt <= 3 )` test to the outer loop or handle it however else you want.